# lldb in xcode detects integer called I to be a complex number

Tags: c, xcode, lldb

I have a C code, within which an `int I` gets declared and initialized. When I'm debugging within xcode, if I try to print the value of `I`, xcode tries to find a complex number:

```
(lldb) p I
error: <lldb wrapper prefix>:43:31: expected unqualified-id
using $__lldb_local_vars::I;
                          ^
<user expression 3>:1760:11: expanded from here
#define I _Complex_I
      ^
<user expression 3>:7162:20: expanded from here
#define _Complex_I ( __extension__ 1.0iF )
```

When I try the same thing (stopping at the same exact line in the code) in the command line, without using xcode, it works fine:

```
(lldb) p I
(int) $0 = 56
```

I'm loading the following libraries:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
```

which shouldn't even include complex numbers, no? I definitely don't have a macro that defines `I` to be the complex variable. The one I run in xcode, I compile with the default xcode tools. The one I run in the command line, I use `gcc`. Is this the difference, somehow? Is xcode including more libraries than I ask it to? Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Edit: I should also add that the variable explorer in xcode shows the value of `I` correctly, as an integer.

Comment: `I` is defined in `<complex.h>`, and `<complex.h>` is not included by default. If it was included, you would get an error when declaring `int I`.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm not including `<complex.h>`, though. And I'm not getting an error declaring `int I`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$__lldb_local_vars` is an artificial namespace that lldb injects into the wrapper it sets up for your expression before compilation so that clang can find the frame's local variables and their types.  The problem comes as others have noted because we also run the preprocessor when compiling your expression, and your variable name collides with a preprocessor symbol in the expression context.

Normally, debug information does not record macros at all, so you aren't seeing the complex.h version of `I` from your own use of it in your code.  Rather, you are seeing the `I` macro because something has caused the Darwin module to be imported into lldb's expression context.

That can happen in two ways, either because you explicitly asked for it by running:

```
(lldb) expr @import Darwin
```

or because you built this program with `-fmodules` and your code imported the Darwin module by inserting a statement like the above.

Doing this by hand is a common trick explicitly to make #defines from the module visible to the expression parser.  Since it is the visibility of the macro that is causing problems, then you will have to stop doing that if you want this expression to succeed.

OTOH, if lldb is doing this because the debug information recorded that some part of you code imported this module, you can turn off the behavior by putting:

```
settings set target.auto-import-clang-modules 0
```

in your ~/.lldbinit and restarting your debug session.

BTW, the `p` command (or the `expression` command that `p` is an alias for) evaluates the text you provide it as a regular expression using the language and in the context of the current frame, with as much access to symbols, defines and the like as lldb can provide.  Most users also want to be able to access class information that might not be directly visible in the current frame, so it tends to cast as wide a net as possible looking for symbols and types in order to enable this.

It is a very powerful feature, but as you are seeing sometimes the desire to provide this wide access for expressions can cause conflicting definitions.  And anyway, it is way more powerful than needed just to view a local variable.

lldb has another command: `frame var` (convenient alias `v`) that prints local variable values by directly accessing the memory pointed to by the debug information and presenting it using the type from the debug info.  It supports a limited subset of C-like syntax for subelement reference; you can use `*` to dereference, `.` or `->` and if the variable is an array `[0]` etc...

So unless you really do need to run an expression (for instance to access a computed property or call another function), `v` will be faster and because its implementation is simpler and more direct, it will have less chance of subtle failures than `p`.

If you also want to access the object definition of some ObjC or Swift local variable, the command `vo` or `frame var -O` will fetch the description of the local variable it finds using the `v` method.

Comment: BTW, `v` or `frame variable` uses the same machinery as the Xcode Locals view (and the same for VSCode, IIUC).

Answer (score 1):

> I definitely don't have a macro that defines I to be the complex variable.

It looks like lldb is getting confused somehow, not an issue with your code, but without a MRE it is hard to say.

> The one I run in xcode, I compile with the default xcode tools. The one I run in the command line, I use gcc. Is this the difference, somehow?

xcode uses "Apple clang" (an old, custom version) with libc++ by default, as far as I know. `gcc` is quite different and it may not even use libc++.

Having said that, since xcode shows the variable as an integer but lldb does not, it looks like something else is going on.

> Is xcode including more libraries than I ask it to?

I don't think so given the program works and Xcode shows the value as an integer.

> Why is this happening and how can I prevent it?

Hard to say since it is a closed source tool. Try to make an MRE. It usually helps debugging the issue and finding workarounds.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to make an MRE. It's a relatively big piece of code I moved to xcode for profiling purposes, so it may take time.

Answer (score 1):

By definition a complex number is not defined as simply `int`

Additionally, as mentioned, complex `I` is defined in <complex.h>:

> To construct complex numbers you need a way to indicate the imaginary
> part of a number. There is no standard notation for an imaginary
> floating point constant. Instead, complex.h defines two macros that
> can be used to create complex numbers.

```
Macro: const float complex _Complex_I

    This macro is a representation of the complex number “0+1i”. Multiplying a real floating-point value by _Complex_I gives a complex number whose value is purely imaginary. You can use this to construct complex constants:

    3.0 + 4.0i = 3.0 + 4.0 * _Complex_I

    Note that _Complex_I * _Complex_I has the value -1, but the type of that value is complex. 

_Complex_I is a bit of a mouthful. complex.h also defines a shorter name for the same constant.

Macro: const float complex I

    This macro has exactly the same value as _Complex_I. Most of the time it is preferable. However, it causes problems if you want to use the identifier I for something else. You can safely write

    #include <complex.h>
    #undef I
```

[Reference here for GNU implementation](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html)

Include this [header](https://code.woboq.org/gcc/include/complex.h.html) file (or similar from your environment), and no need to define it yourself

Comment: Thanks. I'm not defining it, though, and that's the weird thing.

Comment: @sodiumnitrate - That is weird.  But in your post, the error message is explicit, apparently complaining that an <lldb wrapper prefix> ... expected unqualified ID.  I looked here to see if I could find anything...  It contains this line, which appears to be the source of the error message:  `stream.Printf("using $__lldb_local_vars::%s;\n", var_name.AsCString());`  ( from [here](https://lldb.llvm.org/cpp_reference/ClangExpressionSourceCode_8cpp_source.html))  Nothing else of interest through.